# Jquery each loop displays items already added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can anybody advise why my Jquery loop (using each) displays all the past additions aswell? For instance, if I am adding item no 4 and items 1,2,3 are added it will display 1,2,3,1,2,3,4.... Any ideas?

```
  function refreshCart(){
    console.log("in current cart")
    var cartTable = $(".cart-table")
    var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body")
    var productRows = cartBody.find(".cart-product")
    var currentUrl = window.location.href

    var refreshCartUrl = '/api/cart/'
    var refreshCartMethod = "GET";
    var data = {};
    $.ajax ({

      url: refreshCartUrl,
      method: refreshCartMethod,
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success")
        console.log(data)
        if (data.products.length > 1) {
          productRows.html("")

          $.each(data.products, function(index, value) {
            cartBody.append("<tr><th scope=\"row\">" + index + "</th><td colspan=3>" + value + "</td></tr>")
          })
        } else {
          window.location.href = currentUrl
        } 
    },
      error: function(errorData) {
        console.log("error")
        console.log(errorData)
      }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your dom element is not emptied when you refresh the cart a second time. So there's nothing wrong with the loop itself, you just have to empty the dom element before. Like this:

```
$(cartBody).empty()
```

Just do this after you've fetched the cartBody and you should be all set! :)

Comment: After var cartBody = cartTable.find(".cart-body").
I guess you don't need the productRows.html("") row after that, but im not sure.

Comment: thanks, I did it within the loop and that works too. I tested your method aswell and that also works.

Comment: Greatness! Good luck further on, glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

you remove content of cart-product with the line productRows.html("") but you append the content to cart-body without delete his content before. That's why it append the same datas twice. Delete cart-body content before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need few change see following:

```
success: function(data) {
console.log("success")
console.log(data)
if (data.products.length > 1) {

  var allProduct = '';

  $.each(data.products, function(index, value) {
    allProduct += "<tr><th scope=\"row\">" + index + "</th><td colspan=3>" + value + "</td></tr>";
  })

  $(cartBody).html(allProduct); // Replacing your existing html here

} else {
  window.location.href = currentUrl
} 
}
```