# How to stop table body clearing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code where the total price (.cart-total) is not displayed because of the `(cartBody).empty` statement at the beginning of the loop. But I need that in there so that my previously added products do not keep repeating. Any ideas how I can get round this?

```
        if (data.products.length > 1){
            productRows.html("")
            $(cartBody).empty()
            $.each(data.products, function(index, value){
              console.log(value)
                cartBody.append("<tr><td>" + value.name + "</td><td>" + value.price + "</td></tr>")
            })
            cartBody.find(".cart-total").text(data.total)
```

Any help is really appreciated.

HTML:

```
<th>
<td>Product Name</td>
<td>Product Price</td>
</th>
{% for product in cat_appetizers %}
<table>

<tr>   
<td><h5>{{ product.name }}</h5>
<td><p><strong>£ {{ product.price }}</strong></p></td>

<td>
    <form class='form-product-ajax' method="POST" action='{% url "cart:update" %}' data-endpoint='{% url "cart:update" %}' class="form"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}'>
        <span class='submit-span'>
        {% if product in cart.products.all %}
            <button>Remove</button>
        {% else %}
            <button>Add to Basket</button>
        </span>
        {% endif %}
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
{% endfor %} 

<h3>Your order <i class="icon_cart_alt pull-right"></i></h3>
{% if cart.products.exists %}
<table class="cart-table"> <a href="cart"></a>


<tbody class="cart-body">

  <tr class="cart-product">
    {% for product in cart.products.all %}
    <td>
        <a href="#0" class="remove_item"><i class="icon_minus_alt"></i></a> <strong></strong> {{ product.name }}
    </td>
    <td class="cart-price">{{ product.price }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <td class="cart-total">{{ cart.total }}</td>

<tr>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Have you debugged and determined that that's the problem?  Your logic seems to be in the correct order, why do you think the empty() call is affecting what you append after?  Also, you should have semi-colons at the end of your statements.

Comment: Yes I have debugged and that is the problem. But the issue with removing that line is that it repeats my products in the cart. This was resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48687004/jquery-each-loop-displays-items-already-added.

Comment: @Rutnet Sounds like you need to modify how your HTML is structured. If `$(cartBody).empty()` is removing data that you don't want to be removed, you need to change your target. I can't really tell you more without knowing what the HTML in question looks like.

Comment: thanks, I have added my HTML to the question now

Comment: First, I'd recommend cleaning up your HTML. You don't have well-formed HTML and so it makes it much harder to predict the resulting DOM from this. For example, `a` tags should not be direct descendants of `table`s. For every `<tr>` there must be exactly one `</tr>`, etc.

Comment: I think I cleaned it a little bit?

Comment: Ok I have sorted it, thanks for your help @MikeC. I created a new table row which was not part of the table body but still part of the table.

Comment: You're creating a new table with each iteration of your `for` loop because your  `<table>` tag is nested inside the `for` loop.  Your loop should be inside the `<table>` and outside the `<tr>`.